# How to use browserify with brfs without npm or node installed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I'm using browserify with brfs (as described here: [knockout integration with browserify](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html)) and am checking-in to a build controller that doesn't have Node installed, and doesn't have npm installed either. My solution is to check-in node.exe and then do the following to use browserify:

```
.\node.exe .\browserify\bin\cmd.js index.js -o app.js
```

Works great. However, I want to use brfs, and browserify expects this as a transform, e.g.

```
browserify -t brfs main.js > bundle.js
```

Now I can't figure this out because 'brfs' won't be aliased, and I can't figure out how to use my node.exe trick again. What I think I want is this, which obviously doesn't work because parenthesis don't work like this in cmd:

```
.\node.exe .\browserify\bin\cmd.js -t (.\node.exe .\brfs\bin\args.js) index.js -o app.js
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - once I am running browserify using node.exe with my above method, as long as brfs is in my node_modules folder, node/browserify will search the node_modules folder for brfs. Thus, the following works:

```
.\node.exe .\browserify\bin\cmd.js -t brfs index.js -o app.js
```